# How to read grayscale img from a video with OpenCV?

Tags: python, opencv

I read all pictures from my `pic` directory and then convert them each to gray-scale with `canny` edge detections before writing it all to a video.

But, when I use my video software to play it, it shows a green background, and I can't read video frames from it. Could someone show me how to solve it?

**Sample code**

```py
import numpy as np
import cv2 as cv
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fourcc = cv.VideoWriter_fourcc(*"I420")
out = cv.VideoWriter("t2.avi", fourcc, 1, (640, 480), 0)
for pic in glob.glob1("./pic/", "A*"):
    img = cv.imread(f"./pic/{pic}", -1)
    
    edge = cv.Canny(img, 100, 200)
    edge = cv.resize(edge, (640, 480))
    out.write(edge)

out.release()

# Cant read video frame here:
cap = cv.VideoCapture("t2.avi")
ret, frame = cap.read()
if ret:
    plt.imshow(frame)
else:
    print("end")
    cap.release()
```

**Video plays with green background**
[image]

Comment: Are you importing OpenCV as `cv2` or `cv`? Also, what is the output you expect?

Comment: I want the video plays with black-white picture, and I can use `VideoCapture`  to read my content that I already had wrote to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like a compatibility issue between `I420` FOURCC and Grayscale format.

Replace `fourcc = cv.VideoWriter_fourcc(*"I420")` with:

```
fourcc = cv.VideoWriter_fourcc(*"GREY")
```

Note:

- I am using OpenCV 4.5.5 in Windows 10, and it's working with `"GREY"`.
  I am not sure it's going to work in all platforms and versions.

---

`I420` applies colored video.
You may use `I420` with colored video:

Replace `out = cv.VideoWriter("t2.avi", fourcc, 1, (640, 480), 0)` with:

```
out = cv.VideoWriter("t2.avi", fourcc, 1, (640, 480), 1)
```

Convert `edge` to BGR before writing:

```
edge = cv.cvtColor(edge, cv.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)
out.write(edge)
```

---

Code sample using `"GREY"` FOURCC:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2 as cv
#import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import glob

#fourcc = cv.VideoWriter_fourcc(*"I420")
fourcc = cv.VideoWriter_fourcc(*"GREY")
out = cv.VideoWriter("t2.avi", fourcc, 1, (640, 480), 0)
for pic in glob.glob1("./pic/", "A*"):
    img = cv.imread(f"./pic/{pic}", -1)
    
    edge = cv.Canny(img, 100, 200)
    edge = cv.resize(edge, (640, 480))
    out.write(edge)

out.release()

# Cant read video frame here:
cap = cv.VideoCapture("t2.avi")

while True:
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    if ret:
        #plt.imshow(frame)
        cv.imshow('frame', frame)
        cv.waitKey(1000)
    else:
        print("end")
        cap.release()
        break

cv.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Thanks,but use your method, the video software can't play it,I think the video software can only plat colorful  picture.

Comment: I am using Windows 10, and the video is playable with Windows Media Player, with MPC-HC and with VLC media player. The issue is usually the video codec and not the player (some players requires codecs update). It is true that colored video has better compatibility.